# What is a "Scalar Manifold"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, group-theory, supergravity

I'm trying to understand a [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00656) working within the context of $\mathcal{N}=8$ gauged supergravity with gauge group $\rm{SO}(6)$.  There are a number of statements along the lines of:

> *[...]the scalar manifold parameterized by these 18 scalars is:*
>   $$\mathcal{M}_{18}=[ \rm{SO}(1,1) \times \rm{SO}(1,1)] \times \frac{\rm{SO}(4,4)}{\rm{SO}(4) \times \rm{SO}(4)}.$$

Now, I understand that the above manifold has 18 dimensions, but I cannot wrap my head around what it represents globally.  What do the points of a "scalar manifold" represent and how are they related to the scalar fields of the theory?  Based on other remarks in the paper, I don't think it's merely a local thing at the Lie Algebra level.

Comment: Which recent paper?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00656 Sorry should have posted that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,in a Supergravity theory scalar fields are regarded as the coordinates of a suitable differential manifold with a Riemannian metric irrespective of the multiplet they belong to. The choice of multiplet, the number of supersymmetry and space time dimension set geometrical property of manifold.

Increasing the number of supersymmetry beyond $\mathcal{N}=3$ fixes the scalar manifold structure.
In general scalar manifolds are Kahler and Kahler geometry is well known and the only free function in the Lagrangian is Kahler potential which determines Yukawa couplings, susy transformation rules and scalar potential(used for super Higgs effect).

For cases beyond $\mathcal{N}=3$ the scalar manifold is unique for any coupling and describes a coset manifold like $G/H$ with a canonical G-invariant metric.

For more discussion on these things see

Castellani, Auria, Fre:Supergravity and superstrings vol.2.